# Getting T_STRING error when trying to set area for latitude and longitude values

Tags: php

```php
    <?php
                if($row["lat"] > $id[$counter][2]) {
                    $lats = $row["lat"] - $id[$counter][2];
                } else {
                    $lats = $id[$counter][2] - $row["lat"];
                }
                if($row["lng"] > $id[$counter][3]) {
                    $lngs = $row["lng"] - $id[$counter][3];
                } else {
                    $lngs = $id[$counter][3] - $row["lng"];
                }
                if($lats <= 0.0003‬ && $lats >= 0) {                
                    $confirm++;
                }
                if($lngs <= 0.002 && $lngs >= 0) {
                    $confirm++;
                }
    ?>
```

I'm trying to take two coordinates, subtract them for each other, then check if within area. If within area, confirm for future processing. But Im getting a T_STRING error right in the section starting at the IF statement. Im almost positive this is a conversion problem.

Comment: what error precisely are you getting and on whichi line?

Comment: _ignore the reopen vote, I just realized the other question *does* mention invisible characters. I was too fast there, sorry._

Answer (score 0):

There is a `NUL` byte after `0.0003`. That's a nasty invisible character.

[image]

To get rid of it, place the cursor to the left of the `3`, press <kbd>➔</kbd> once, and then press <kbd>Del</kbd>. It will apparently do nothing, but this will have deleted the invisible character. Now your code should work.

---

To simplify this for you though, I have cleaned up this line for you (replace the line in your code with this cleaned one, copying from here):

```php
                if($lats <= 0.0003 && $lats >= 0) {
```

Comment: That's cool, what did you use to see this?

Comment: I pasted it in https://phpcodechecker.com/, saw the error at a seemingly correct place and then looked in a hex editor (I used [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/de/hxd/))

Comment: How does this occur?

Comment: Very hard to say, it can come from all kinds of places depending on what you did with that code before. However my experience is that something like this happens to me maybe once a year on average in a way where I have no idea why and can't trace the source back - and if it happens to you more often you'd probably very soon identify a pattern as to what you did to get such a character introduced into your code ;)